# What software can I use to control access to a private video

Tags: video, web

My dad consults and he often does one on one training. A company reached out to him and asked if he could record his videos and they would then pay him per view. Does anyone know of software that we could use so the videos would be hosted and then when they access the video we can see who it was and when and how often they have accessed it for reporting purposes?